# Migrate web application from xmapp to lamp

Tags: linux, apache, codeigniter

I have developed web application using codeigniter on xampp server.
and want to deploy it on LAMP server. I have migrated database and app successfully but facing some problem.

When request web page using browser its not show anything not even error.

I have enabled selinux,
have root account and testing using root account

virtual host file config in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/hotelking.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.hotelking.com
   ServerAlias hotelking.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/hotelking/app/
   Customlog "logs/www.hotelking.com.log" combined
   ErrorLog "log/www.hotelking.com.error_log"
```

```
<Directory /var/www/hotelking/app/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And error log have following error

[Wed Jan 06 03:20:14.515526 2016] [:error] [pid 6912] [client 127.0.0.1:40964] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MY_controller' not found in /var/www/hotelking/app/application/controllers/master.php on line 5
[Wed Jan 06 03:20:21.773841 2016] [:error] [pid 6908] [client 127.0.0.1:40965] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MY_controller' not found in /var/www/hotelking/app/application/controllers/master.php on line 5

I CHECKED IT HAS MY_controller at give location

Comment: Can you update your questions with more info. Like configuration, logs etc. From above description we cannot figure out what's issue.

Comment: tell me what do you want

Comment: Told you like configurations , logs... This will help users to find out what exactly the problem is and they will provide you some solution.

Comment: I have added the required info Siddharth

Comment: Convention of controller name is wrong. "MY_controller" should be "my_controller" or "My_controller".
use this link for reference : - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: @Siddharthsharma, The question is about Codeigniter not CakePHP. There is no problem with file naming.

Comment: If `master.php` is extending 'MY_controller.php` which itself extends `CI_controller.php` you are running up against an age old problem. Search for answers to "extending ci_controller" here and your favorite search site.

Comment: If it's working on XAMPP then the problem should not be in your code, but rather in one of the config files. Did you check index.php and config.php? You are probably not catching enough debug info. Switch on CI Profiler, set the highest verbose level in PHP (and enable temporarily error output in the pho.ini)

Comment: MY_controller.php should be MY_Controller.php

Comment: yes i have on log threshold=4 but its not generating any error in my log folder

Comment: in web error log i got following 


in web error log i got following 


[Thu Jan 07 19:50:46.192932 2016] [:error] [pid 13161] [client 127.0.0.1:57337] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/hotelking/app/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/hotelking/app/index.php on line 202


and code in index.php line no 202 is



require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: PROBLEM IS SOLVE I HAVE NOT SET PERMISSION TO DIRECTORY